# Plotting a list of objects using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of objects in which each object represents a point with an x and y value.

```
class point:
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

I am trying to plot the list of objects using matplotlib but as of right now im not sure of the best implementation of plotting an object with multiple values. Currently I am using a for loop to iterate through the list and plot the values but the graph has unordered axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for z in range(len(list)):
   plt.plot(points[z].x,points[z].y, "bo") 
plt.show()
```

[image: X and Y axis are out of order]

I am unexperienced with python and matplotlib, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The approach looks correct. Your problem seems to be that the coordinates of the points are not numbers. Make sure that `self.x` and `self.y` are numerical values and not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you need to make sure your values are numerical, rather than string.

Here is a way to make your plot, both ensuring that it is numerical, and with a different iteration process, in which you don't add points to your plot one by one:

```
x_vals,y_vals = zip(*[(float(i.x),float(i.y)) for i in list_of_points])

plt.scatter(x_vals,y_vals)
plt.show()
```

(I took the liberty to rename your `list` to `list_of_points`, as you shouldn't be using `list` as a variable name, as otherwise you shadow the built in `list` type)

What it does is turn your list of `point` objects into two lists, one for x values, and one for y values, which are then nice and easy to plot with `matplotlib`.

Comment: With the same logic, a one-style solution would be `plt.plot(*zip(*[(float(p.x),float(p.y)) for p in points]), "bo")`